# Capture high-resolution image snapshots from webcam, in Java

Tags: java, webcam, image-capture

Anyone knows a Java library which can be used for the purpose of capturing high-resolution image snapshots from a webcam?

More precisely:
 - Detect the available webcams (laptops may have a built-in one and an external one attached trough an USB connection)
 - Choose a webcam to work with.
 - Detect available resolutions for IMAGE capture (ex: up to 1280x1024 for a web camera with 1.3 Mp sensor).
   They are generally much greater than the for VIDEO capture (ex: up to 640x480 for the same web camera).
 - Choose a resolution to work with.
 - On request (calling an API function), capture a snapshot from the selected camera with the selected resolution.

I've tried:
 - JMF: sucks, doesn't support automatic detection of attached web cameras.
 - FMJ: uses LTI-CIVIL for webcam support.
 - LTI-CIVIL: only supports VIDEO capture. 
   The code is also very old (2007 if i remember correctly).
   Uses native libraries written in C++ for webcam access. 
   DirectX for Windows and Video4Linux for (obviously, ) Linux.
   But looking over the C++ code, it becomes obvious that it's oriented towards 
   video streaming which is not my purpose (as reflected in the description of what i need)

I would be thankful if anyone could point me to a Java library which fits the profile i need.

Thanks.

Comment: Any particular reason you cannot use a native Windows framework?

Comment: Native Windows does not support grabbing > 640 x 480 resolution from Webcams, either.

Answer (score 2):

openCV is a popular C++ computer vision library. However, they have Java bindings as well.
http://code.google.com/p/javacv/

OpenCV lets u access to image and video processing and capturing of image and video from multiple webcams as well.

Answer (score 1):

This Java API should do the job: http://webcam-capture.sarxos.pl/
The following code takes a picture and saves it as a .png file in the project's workspace folder. Be sure to look through the creator's other examples on their website.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam;

public class TakePictureExample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // get default webcam and open it
    Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
    webcam.open();

    // get image
    BufferedImage image = webcam.getImage();

    // save image to PNG file
    ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File("test.png"));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following open source project, **webcamstudio** http://code.google.com/p/webcamstudio/ has done a great job using Java for webcam support. Perhaps take some ideas from there.

Comment: Thanks, but i think i'll try openCV first (recommended below).

Comment: @Michael, can you share your research? Did you find any good java library?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JMyron](http://webcamxtra.sourceforge.net/index.shtml), the library is [here](http://webcamxtra.sourceforge.net/distro/JMyron0025.zip) and you can see how it works with [this](http://webcamxtra.sourceforge.net/distro/JMyron_SimpleCamera_Eclipse.zip) example

Comment: Well, the example shows capturing a video stream (this i can do already with lti-civil). Will try openCV and if that fails too i'll try jMyron, thanks for the info.